# ini_set include_path not working

Tags: php, include, ini

It seems something on my server has been changed, and I'm seeing the inclusion failed error message on my every website on the server, here is one example:

```
Warning: require(xconstants_fa.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/blahblah/public_html/fa/companies/ads/index.php on line 26
```

And in line 26 it says:

```
ini_set ("include_path", "../../includes/");
require "xconstants_fa.php";
```

So it's obvious that somehow my server has stopped using the "ini_set" function(because it was just working fine before), I looked into php.ini disable_functions, nothing is there, I commented all the disabled functions and also the open_basedir, not working there.

and if I:

```
ini_set ("include_path", "../../includes/") or die('ERROR HERE');
```

It echos `ERROR HERE` on the page

What's happening here? I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Same question (by same user) but this time with accepted answer over at server-fault: [ini_set include_path not working](http://serverfault.com/q/505107/69499).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the actual function to change the include_path [set_include_path()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php):

```
$path = '../../includes/';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```

Comment: This is a CMS and I don't want to go into each line of it and change them, I just need it to work like yesterday :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php ini_set('include_path',ini_get('include_path').':../../includes/:');  ?>
```